# Transforming date with Redshift

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift, intervals

I am creating an end of month variable, that works with postgres but I have to rewrite it in Redshift, any clue why it shows me the following error?

The database reported a syntax error: Amazon Invalid operation: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported code: 8001 context: i

```
select
(date_trunc('month', ("Date (id created)" + INTERVAL '1 month'))) as "EoM"
from id
```

Answer (score 6):

Redshift uses dateadd to apply intervals to timestamps

```
select date_trunc(month, ( dateadd(month,1,"Date (id created)"))) as "EoM"
from id
```

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html

Comment: Thank you, that works! Do I have to pay attention when using current_date instead of a date variable? Example: ```select "Date (id created)" >= date_trunc('month', dateadd(month,18, current_date)```

Comment: Also what are the options to subtract a month from a date? Would I also use dateadd()?

Answer (score 3):

Redshift supports the "last_day()" function that returns the date of the last day of any month.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LAST_DAY.html

This is a useful function for these calculations.

Redshift cannot add a month or a year since there is no single length for these intervals.  If you do want to keep on your current route you can truncate the date you are interested in to the month level, add 35 days, then truncate to month again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get days of a month, where your timestamp is first day of the month

```
SELECT datediff(day,timestamp,dateadd(month,1,timestamp))
```